# Laravel: Writing right nested conditional queries (code reduction)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, refactoring

Ok, so this is my code.

What it does is check some worker's fields to find posible duplicates (I know this fields should be unique, but I can't do so much about that). So for instance if the field `$credential_no` is set, it checks in DB, but if it's null, it doesn't because I don't want all the records that has null in that field.

[image]

The thing here, is that I need to check if at least some of that inputs (`$credential_no || $ssn || $passport_no || $birthdate`) are defined because if not, the query will returns all the workers, cause are none `where` condition, and I want results only if there's a match.

Also, by trying, I realice that I can use `where` and `orWhere` indistinctly, am I wrong? because if not I must use something like this:
[image]

My question is how can I make this thing better, how can I reduce this messy code, or there is no way in laravel to do this kind of thing?

**Update 1**

Ok soo, following the advice of @btl, I came with this, but as you can see I must call `get()` inside the first argument function (and I think I should not do this), cause if I don't pass the second argument function, and call `get()` after the last `})` this code will return all the records, what I do not want.

[image]

Comment: This code can certainly be cleaned up, but without knowing more about the origins of the values (i.e how is `$passport_no` defined?) it's difficult to clean it up properly. Please update the question to include all of the relevant code.

Comment: You can pass a 2nd closure to `when` for cases where the conditional resolves to false: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: @sam all values come from inputs, that doesn't matter

Comment: @btl I like your like your approach, let me update.

Comment: For your orWhere issue, it was changed in laravel 5.3. Therefore, if you have laravel < 5.3, orWhere is the same as where if you didn't call where before. This is not true in laravel >= 5.3. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

Comment: Thanks @AlexvanVliet , can you help me to improve this code please? and do you know how the people on the laravel project recommend to handle this then?